# how to find the starter bootstrap template - not found

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, admin, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi is there an official bootstrap admin blank template from the official site?
looking for the real official starter template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admin: http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin/

Check: http://startbootstrap.com/ for all templates.

Comment: the issue is that it seems to connect to some .co.uk site so thats why I was looking to see if bootstrap official site offer something like this template without hidden inner links.

Comment: @st2011, if you developed an admin theme using Bootstrap, it would be equally "official" as sb-admin. `startbootstrap.com` (and sb-admin) are neither affiliated, nor endorced by "official" bootstrap (`getbootstrap.com`).

Answer (score 1):

The official Bootstrap templates are here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

However, there is not an official "admin" starter template.

Also, there is a collection of starter templates here: http://bootply.com/templates

Comment: Thanks, awesome resources.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official admin template for starter.
But you can check admin template that can be used as starter template [here](https://themeselection.com/products/chameleon-admin-free-bootstrap-dashboard-template/)